# Regression using unordered combinations, sign of predictor depends on order

Tags: regression, linear-model, experiment-design

First time poster here. Is there anything wrong with the following regression approach?

**EDIT:**
After following the advice of the accepted answer to include the multiple-membership effect, I wanted to post an update of the result. I used a combination of the approaches in [this tutorial on multiple-membership modeling](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/multimember.html) and [this tutorial on mixed effect visualization](https://www.azandisresearch.com/2022/12/31/visualize-mixed-effect-regressions-in-r-with-ggplot2/).

[image]

**Background:**

I am dealing with fuel consumption $F$ of a vehicle under a variety of conditions. I have developed a way to infer the difference between two samples $\hat{\Delta F}=\delta\hat{f}_i-\delta\hat{f}_j$, and I want to regress that against the actual difference in two samples $\Delta F=\hat{F}_i-\hat{F}_j$. The inference is useful because there are many situations where I could assume that $\delta\hat{f}_j$ is zero, allowing me to directly estimate the fuel consumption change without a reference case.
The model matrix starts with a row per sample, then I augment it. Each sample is presumably independent, so I want to test all $n\choose 2$ combinations.

**Original Model Matrix**

| Sample | Fuel Consumed $F$ | Additional Fuel Inferred $\hat{F}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $f_1$ | $\delta\hat{f}_1$ |
| $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ |
| $n$ | $f_n$ | $\delta\hat{f}_n$ |

**Augmented Model Matrix**

| Sample $i$ | Sample $j$ | Actual Fuel Difference $\Delta F$ | Inferred Fuel Difference $\hat{\Delta F}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | $f_1-f_2$ | $\delta\hat{f}_1-\delta\hat{f}_2$ |
| $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ |
| $n \choose k$ rows | $n \choose k$ rows | $f_i-f_j$ | $\delta\hat{f}_i-\delta\hat{f}_j$ |

The goal is to show that the inference matches the actual savings, so I regress $\Delta F \sim \hat{\Delta F}$.

One specific question I had is should I be working with absolute values for $\Delta F$ and $\hat{\Delta F}$, since the statistics are ordered but the combinations are not?

---

Here's an example output. For the curious, the "conditions" causing the fuel change are platooning, which can drastically improve (but sometimes hurt) fuel economy

[image: A figure of actual fuel difference versus inferred fuel difference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't strike me as hopeless or deeply flawed. I however think you'd want to account for the pairwise structure of your data. I.e. any error/noise in measuring $f_i$ is going to affect all pairs including $f_i$ in the same way.

One way to account for this is to include a random effect for each measurement, i.e. something like:

$$
\Delta F_{i,j} \sim N(\mu_{i,j}, \sigma)\\
\mu_{i,j} = \alpha + \beta \widehat{\Delta F_{i,j}} + \gamma_i - \gamma_j \\
\gamma_i \sim N(0, \tau)
$$

Where $\gamma_i$ represents the error in measuring $f_i$. This is a type of *multiple-membership* model (see e.g. https://github.com/jvparidon/lmerMultiMember for a package discussing and implementing those).

I've seen a similar (though not identical!) model used in the context of ecology (https://www.mdpi.com/1424-2818/14/10/858) - more generally, ecologist have a vast literature on modelling pairwise distances between samples and the linked paper provides an IMHO reasonable entry point into that literature.

I think using absolute values would pose more problems (now you have a lower bound at zero) than it solves - if your outcome distribution is symmetric around 0 (e.g. normal) and you have chosen the order of pairs randomly I think you are safe.

Hope that clarifies more than confuses.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out a random effect model, I appreciate the references. The phenomena that you describe is visible in the plot I attached in the (-2,5) region, I'm sure that is one noisy observation causing a deviation. For clarity, there are multiple groups as well, so the plot comes from $G$ concatenated tables. I assume the group $G$ would also get a $\gamma$ parameter.